# NIC link going up/down repeatedly on ibm x3250, e1001e driver when trying to obtain ip addr via dhcp

Tags: linux, dhcp, intel

I just bought a brand new x3250 rack from IBM. The NIC is  Intel 82574L Gigabit Ethernet Controller. I installed CentOS 5.5 on it. The problem I'm having is that I cant get an ip on the machine via dhcp. In /var/log/messages  I see e1001e NIC link is up and then e1001e NIC link is down repeatedly... it's just fluctuating up/down like its on steroids or something. I've verified that the cable works. Both ends are gigabit ethernet with auto-neg enabled. I booted from a live cd of linux mint and I see exactly the same problem there as well.. I can give the interface a static ip and ping loopback. That's it. I defined a static route but couldn't even manage to ping the gateway router on the same subnet. 
This is such a pain. You buy a new server and this is what you get for starters. Has anybody else had this problem? Any help would me much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the interface goes up and down this means that the transceiver does not see the carrier from the remote NIC. You have to check everything on the path from the remote transceiver (e. g. switch port) to your NIC. May be the cable is not CAT5 or when it was crimped the it was untwisted too much. Check the path with a [TDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer).